# Is it possible to return a SOAP message in a non alphabetical order in JAVA?

Tags: java, soap, alphabetical

I trying to set the order of the return types in my soap return message but it keeps printing out alphabetically. Is there a way I can change the order of my return types?

I'm setting the types in the order C, A, B but it always prints out ABC.

Web Method

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "Method")
    @WebResult(name="myType")    
    public MyType Method(@WebParam(name = "string1") String string1, @WebParam(name = "string2") String string2,@WebParam(name = "string3") String string3) {

        MyType mt = new MyType();

        mt.setC(string3);
        mt.setA(string1);
        mt.setB(string2);

        return mt;
    }
```

MyType Class

```
public class MyType {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }


}
```

Current Soap Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:MethodResponse xmlns:ns2="http://bbb/">
            <myType>
                <a>one</a>
                <b>two</b>
                <c>three</c>
            </myType>
        </ns2:MethodResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Ideal Soap Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:MethodResponse xmlns:ns2="http://bbb/">
            <myType>
                <c>three</c>
                <a>one</a>
                <b>two</b>
            </myType>
        </ns2:MethodResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm rewriting a delphi WS in Java and we want to deploy the new java WS without making any changes to the clients who connect. So we are trying to make the Java WS response exactly the same as the delphi one. The response we get from the delphi WS isn't in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it by adding JAXB annotations to the `MyType` class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(propOrder = {"c", "a", "b"})
public class MyType {
  //...
```

but if you're trying to duplicate an existing service then by far the best approach is to use `wsimport` to generate Java classes that match the existing WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the methods in the bean, maybe, not the calling order which has definitely no bearing on the resulting XML. But more importantly, use a WSDL where you can properly specify the schema of the response, and then generate the beans from it using `wsdl2java`.

Comment: Yes I tried changing the order of the bean too which also didn't help. Ok thanks, I'll need to do some research on your other suggestion - still very new at this. Thanks!